# Incoherence in the biblatex package

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I apologize in advance if these questions have been asked and answered before.  I have trouble with biblatex package and I am very confused about it.
In short, here is a minimal code that I am trying to achieve.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

 \addbibresource{Reference1.bib}

\begin{document}


Lorem \cite{RuizHerrera1993b}, 
ipsum \cite{Bibitemmr1880658Niculescu2001b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With the following reference

```
@Article{RuizHerrera1993b,
  author    = {Ruiz-Herrera, Alfonso},
  journal   = {Discrete & Continuous Dynamical Systems - A},
  title     = {Chaos in delay differential equations with applications in population dynamics},
  year      = {1993},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {1633-1644},
  volume    = {33},
  address   = {Boston, MA, USA},
  date      = {1993},
  doi       = {10.3934/dcds.2013.33.1633},
  publisher = {American Institute of Mathematical Sciences (AIMS)},
}

@Article{Bibitemmr1880658Niculescu2001b,
  author    = {Bibitem{mr1880658} Niculescu, , S.-I and {it}, journal = {Delay Effects on Stability}; Lecture Notes in Control and Information Sciences},
  year      = {2001},
  pages     = {269},
  address   = {London, UK},
  date      = {2001},
  publisher = {Springer},
}

@Article{Bibitemmr1433374Shampineb,
  author = {Bibitem{mr1433374} Shampine, L and Reichelt, M},
  title  = {The MATLAB ODE suite. {em SIAM}, journal = {J. Sci. Comput.} {bf}, date = {1997}, year = {1997}, pages = {1--22}, volume = {18}, doi = {10.1137/S1064827594276424}},
}
```

When I enter this into winedt console i receive an error message:

```
No file Question.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 10.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 10.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'RuizHerrera1993b' on page 1 undefined on input line 13
.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Bibitemmr1880658Niculescu2001b' on page 1 undefined on
 input line 14
```

I tried to solve the problem but I haven't been able to resolve it so far.
I apologise in advance if the question isn't that clear.
Any help would be immensely apreciated!!!

Comment: You need to run biber after the pdflatex run and then pdflatex again. And correct the author in the bib entry.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher Thank you for your hint.

Comment: As Ulrike says: Your document needs to be compiled with Biber. A full compile cycle would involve at least pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you use an editor to compile your document for you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: That said, your `.bib` file has some issues (that are not the cause of the warning messages you show, but should be fixed). Firstly, the unescaped `&` in `RuizHerrera1993b`'s `journal` field will cause a LaTeX error. It should be `journal   = {Discrete \& Continuous Dynamical Systems},`. The entries `Bibitemmr1880658Niculescu2001b` and `Bibitemmr1433374Shampineb` appear to have extremely odd `author` and `title` fields that contain data that should be in other fields.

Comment: Do things work for you now that you compile with Biber (and have fixed your `.bib` entries a bit)? Or is there something else that needs doing?